# MongoDB Search Query Weights

Tags: java, mongodb, search, indexing, nosql

We have search scenario where weights are assigned to different fields of mongodb document, suppose one of the fields has weight 40 assigned, i am looking for some solution as if any of portion in the text field is matched it should return score 40 but in real case it returns different score like 20.444 or sometimes 200.00 if whole string is matched, is there a way to limit to return maximum score of 40?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. The assigned weights "to the index" are used relative to the "number of matches" and things like "relative to start of text" as well as "total length of text", and the general common fare for text search. If you want a "custom algorithm", then you would need to resort to projecting your own calculated "score" via the aggregation framework.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for your reply, is there any example code for that aggregation? i am new to MongoDB